# Facebook PHP SDK V3 login token - Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException:

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

The code below works fine with the PHP SDK v3. However, I had to use a java sdk login at first and now I don't know how to get a token with PHP or check if the user is logged in or not with PHP. I GET THE ERROR BELOW.

I can not use the SDK 4 yet as my hosting will not allow it. Long story. I have tried SEVERAL sites and tutorials for the past few hours to no avail. Can someone show me a simple way to do this? With code examples? What do I need to change the canvas url to on the Facebook app? etc..

**Here is an error I get without the login.**
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in

```
require 'Facebook3/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'myID',
  'secret' => 'MySecret',
));

$attachment = array(
    'message' => 'COOL',
    'name' => 'Some Info',
    'caption' => "more info",
    'link' => 'http://aLink.com',
    'description' => 'View Trailer Here!',
    'picture' => 'http://Picture.com/images/aPic.png',
    'actions' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Get Search',
            'link' => 'http://www.google.com',
        )
    )
);



$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```